# How to collapse all issues in the Xcode issue navigator

Tags: xcode, macos

I am porting a huge C++ project to OS X. After my initial compile with Xcode I have multiple errors in many files I want to investigate.

Problem is that the issue navigator shows all files non collapsed after each compile:

[image]

So I have to collapse all of them by hand (there a a lot of files) after each compile to have an overview of a files which need fixing.

Is there a hotkey or a setting to collapse all files?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

<kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>-click one of the little disclosure triangles to collapse (or expand) all rows.
[image]

Comment: Okay works I tested it. More precise: cmd-click collapsed all child issues.

Comment: It seems that it's actually alt-click not cmd click.

Comment: It's cmd-click for me. Maybe you've remapped the shortcut or your keyboard.

Comment: One of the many hidden and non-intuitive features created by Apple. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: Alt - Cmd - Click did it for me.

Comment: The Tests navigator too seems to expand all items at will, all the time. Very annoying if you have lots of test cases and want to run only one that is down the list. Thank you!

Comment: None of the above work for me.

Answer (score 27):

let me add some extra info, when tapping a main item

hold ⌘ to : close a type of warnings

hold shift & ⌘ to : close **all** types of warnings

Comment: Thumbs up for - hold shift & ⌘

Comment: Might be rare, but is it documented somewhere ?

Comment: didn't see it in documentation or online, was just guessing that the developers of xcode might have added it, and yeah, it's there.

Answer (score 2):

go to the most top level of issue and `alt` + `<-` keyboard arrow key that will close that issue and when you use `alt` + `->` to open the issue again. all issue is collapse